# How to install Java 11 on AWS EMR

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-emr, amazon-eks

Am trying to install java 11 on EMR and below is my docker file

```
FROM 711395599931.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/spark/emr-6.2.0:latest 
ARG GIT_COMMIT=unspecified
LABEL git_commit=$GIT_COMMIT
USER root
CMD apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y java-11-amazon-corretto && \
    apt-get install -y ant && \
    apt-get clean;
ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto.x86_64
USER hadoop:hadoop
```

and am pushing this custom EMR image to ECR repo. Below is the command am using to submit the job into the cluster and using **spark.kubernetes.container.image** in the job submission as below

```
aws emr-containers start-job-run \
  --virtual-cluster-id=$VIRTUAL_CLUSTER_ID \
  --name=testSparkReaderWithDocker \
  --execution-role-arn=$EMR_ROLE_ARN \
  --release-label=emr-6.2.0-latest \
  --job-driver='{
    "sparkSubmitJobDriver": {
      "entryPoint": "s3://sample-bucket/dp-person-spark-reader-poc-with-docker.jar",
      "sparkSubmitParameters": "--class Main --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=2960******.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/dp-spark-emr-custom-image:latest --conf spark.executor.instances=1 --conf spark.executor.memory=2G --conf spark.executor.cores=2 --conf spark.driver.cores=2"
    }
  }' \
  --configuration-overrides '{
    "monitoringConfiguration": {
      "persistentAppUI": "ENABLED",
      "s3MonitoringConfiguration": {
         "logUri": "s3://sample-bucket/logs"
      }
    }
  }'
```

this throws below error

```
/usr/lib/spark/bin/spark-class: line 72: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto.x86_64/bin/java: No such file or directory
/usr/lib/spark/bin/spark-class: line 97: CMD: bad array subscript
```

Any help on this would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change the line

`ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto.x86_64`

to

`ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto`

If that doesn't work run, build your Dockerfile and then run a container with the image with this command to get a Bash shell inside the container.

`docker run -it your_image_name:your_tag /bin/bash`

First you should make sure the Java binary found in your path is Corretto. Run this to check.

`java -version`

You should see an output that references the version of Corretto found.

```
openjdk 11.0.17 2022-10-18 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-11.0.17.8.1 (build 11.0.17+8-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-11.0.17.8.1 (build 11.0.17+8-LTS, mixed mode)
```

If you don't see Corretto or you get an error java is not found, you should probably stop and figure out why.

Then, use these commands still inside the container Bash shell to figure out where Corretto is installed and what your JAVA_HOME value should be.

`readlink -f $(which java)`

Drop this `/bin/java` of the end of whatever this returns, and use it for your JAVA_HOME value. So for example if the output is `/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java` use `/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64`

Then back in your Dockerfile change the line to use that path.

`ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64`